# List of supported devices and drivers for ethtool --cable-test

Tags: linux-networking, ethernet, ethtool

I want to use ethtool to test a network cable with `ethtool --cable-test` and `ethtool --cable-test-tdr`.
I tried to do this (as root) on my machine (internal network adapter), two USB-to-Ethernet adapters and the internal adapter of the raspberry pi4.
In all cases I got `Unsupported Operation`. It seems that only specific devices and drivers support this feature.
Is there any list showing which ones? I could not find one myself.
On my machine I have arch linux, so I have the newest Linux kernel (6.6.6-arch1-1).

Would be really great if one of you can point me in the right direction, how to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following:

Checked the source for ethtool to see what netlink messages it was using when querying cable test results (e.g. `nl_cable_test` and `nl_cable_test_tdr`).  I then followed those through into the kernel driver source tree, and it looks like the following ethernet PHY drivers support basic cable test of some sort:

```
drivers/net/phy/at803x.c
drivers/net/phy/bcm-phy-lib.h
drivers/net/phy/nxp-c45-tja11xx.c
drivers/net/phy/nxp-tja11xx.c
drivers/net/phy/adin.c
drivers/net/phy/micrel.c
drivers/net/phy/bcm-phy-lib.c
drivers/net/phy/phy_device.c
drivers/net/phy/marvell.c
drivers/net/phy/microchip_t1.c
drivers/net/phy/bcm54140.c
```

... for a full list of supported NIC chips, you'd have to look at those source files and elsewhere in the code to see which NIC hardware that applies to.

The only one that supports TDR testing (as of Linux 6.7.0) was the marvell phy driver.  Other comments elsewhere in the source (e.g. NIC IC header files) suggest that various other chips also have some soft of hardware TDR functionality (including some ancient hardware), but it looks like they remain unimplemented.

The Marvell TDR test support seems to have been added by Andrew Lunn, and there are a couple of videos on YT in which he presents the work.